# The expression " x = (a,b); "

Tags: c++, expression, comma-operator

In this comma-separated expression. Why doesn't the x gets value an instead of b?

```
int main() {

int a=20;
int b=100;
int x;
x=(a,b);

cout<<x;
}
```

Gives output: 100

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator evaluates the left hand side, discards it, evaluates the right hand side, returns it.

Comment: yeah, why not close as duplicate? this is so obvious